# Mirror items on a model

Tags: mirror-modifier

[image]

When trying to apply object locations to this mirrored object it makes the "x" part of the mirror it goes far away from where it should be. And when I rotate the entire object all mirrored parts go weird.  how to i resolve this?

Comment: The _Mirror_ modifier mirrors the mesh in relation to the object's origin point, as you can see in your screenshot - the orange dot is in the center between the two mirrored half parts of the mesh. If you want to mirror something regardless of the self origin of the mesh, you can specify a _Mirror Object_ in the modifier and the geometry gets mirrored on that origin.

Comment: Applying the location will move the object origin. As Gordon says, as the origin is used as the center of the mirror, it will affect how the object will be mirrored.

Comment: You usually never apply the Objects Location. The Scale and Rotation should be applied before adding modifiers so that the results are consistent. But applying the location just moves the Origin of the object to (o,o,o). This usually messes a lot of things up. In your case, just move the origin back to where it was by selecting the big ring of vertices and pressing Shift+S->To selection

Answer (score 1):

The comments give you some hints, but let me provide a little more extensive answer to specifically get out of your situation.

The *Mirror* modifier needs a reference transform to know how to mirror. By default that is the **local transform** (a.k.a. pivot point, yellow dot, object's origin) of the object where the modifier is added. This can be best seen using the *Local* option from the *Transform Orientations* dropdown:

[image]

Now, when you apply transforms this will change the local transform and the modifier gets "weird". As @GordonBrinkmann points out, this can be changed by setting a *Mirror Object* in the modifier. Maybe you're lucky and have some fitting object just in place for mirroring, but if not
[*Empties*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/empties.html) come in handy as they contain no geometry. They are purely local transforms and that is what we need. If your object is still aligned you may get away with moving the empty easily to the correct position, but if it's oriented arbitrarily in space this can be become hard to get right. So here is a general approach for that.

First, create a helper face which represents the mirror plane (i stick roughly to your scene):

[image]

Now add an empty and use the [*Snap*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html) tool to align it to our helper face:

[image]

With the empty aligned, we can remove the helper face again. Now add the mirror modifier and use the empty as its local transform. Note that the mirror setup is now dependent on the empty and not the mirrored object:

[image]

Done, the local tansform of the mirrored object is now independent regarding the modifier:

[image]

Bonus: if you parent the empty to the mirrored object, you can conveniently move the object around without altering the mirror effect accidently and the empty has a nice place regarding *Outliner* organisation.